# Ember CLI project crashes when I change CSS file. Am I missing something?

Tags: ember-cli

I'm pretty new to Ember but have used Ember CLI to create a project and am on my way. Lots to learn but I'm very impressed so far.

Anyway, my understanding is that Ember CLI projects use broccoli's file-watching features to create a "continuous development" environment. I've seen it in action: as I change templates or javascript files, my changes are immediately apparent when I switch back to the browser.

But when I make changes to css files, my app crashes. Console output is below. Note that when I restart the app with `ember server`, everything works as exepected. So this isn't some CSS syntax error or the like.

So ... this sure seems like a bug to me, but I'm so new around here that I'm wondering if I'm just missing something very basic.

We're not talking SASS files, either. I'm getting this error if I change a single character in a very small /app/styles/app.css - the one generated by `ember new`. I've also tried moving the style rule to a file called my.css and leaving app.css empty except for this one line: `@import 'my.css';` No love.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance,

-Billy B

```
D:\BitBucket\dispatch-alert\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\node_modules\sane\index.js:246
Object.keys(this.dirRegistery[dir]).forEach(function(file, i, arr) {
     ^
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
at Function.keys (native)
at Watcher.detectChangedFile (D:\BitBucket\dispatch-alert\node_modules\ember
-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\node_modules\sane\index.js:246:10)
at Watcher.normalizeChange (D:\BitBucket\dispatch-alert\node_modules\ember-c
li\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\node_modules\sane\index.js:280:10)
at FSWatcher.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1039:12)
```

Update:

Based on the help I've gotten so far (thank you guys) and poking around a bit, I have a theory: because I can edit files in other directories and other editors just fine, I conclude that app/styles is just plain not in the list of "watched" directories. This could be a simple error of omission, but I"m wondering if it isn't deliberate. Wouldn't this directory be one that is processed by Compass and other CSS preprocessors, which might have their own file watching systems or otherwise have problems with watched files? Perhaps the makers of ember-cli have deliberately omitted this directory?

How do I find this out? And what should I do? Head over to the ember-cli project and ask for assistance there? I tried to find where a list of watched directories might be kept, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: Which version of ember-cli are you using?

Comment: are you using sublime (3)? I've been able to track this error down to sublime. When I change the app.css/.less file in another editor it works..

Comment: @JeroenHoek, I'm using ember-cli 0.0.36.

Comment: @AyKarsi, I am indeed using Sublime 3. WebStorm produces the same results, but interestingly when I edit using NotePad (I'm on Windows), everything works as expected

Comment: I'd actually rule out that the styles folder is not being watched. because the error being thrown is in the sane library, which has the sole purpose of watching files. (I created an issue there , even though I'm not 100%, that that is where the problem stems from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401900/ember-cli-project-crashes-when-i-change-css-file-am-i-missing-something/24412748#24412748)

Comment: I'm afraid your theory is incorrect; `app/styles` is watched by default. Ember-cli sets up a Broccoli pipeline where CSS, SASS, LESS, or Stylus stylesheets are preprocessed with broccoli-plugins. Preprocessing assets is part of its raison d'etre.

Comment: If you are going to file an issue with ember-cli, the best thing you can do is create a new project with `ember new`, and try to replicate the issue with several editors. Also, did you read the bit about Sublime 3 in the docs? See: http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/

Comment: The problem is actually that app/styles being watched twice: once via ./app and again via ./app/styles. I've created an issue in ember-cli with more info: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1166

Comment: Watched twice. Right. I put your workaround in .../node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\node_modules\sane. It did fire and did prevent crash, but I got `"Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\BitBucket\dispatch-alert\dist\.gitkeep'`. Regardless I thank you for your help! I will await the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for the moment is to alter the index.js in line 246 (according in your error and my error messages) in the sane module and add something like this:

```
if (!this.dirRegistery[dir]){
    console.log('error',' empty/unkown dir',dir);
    callback();
    return;
}
```

No idea if this is is valid fix. Somehow this is related to sublime. (Caching, File-lock?)..

Comment: I put this code in, and the empty/unknown dir is app/styles. (Thanks for that snippet, btw). Based on what I've seen so far, I have a theory. See my edits and questions, above.